# When add a custom view in Android Toolbar, there will be a marginLeft

Tags: android, toolbar, android-custom-view

I have some problems about android toolbar. Normally if I set a custom view into toolbar, the view should fill the whole toolbar space from left to right and has no margin.

but mine has a empty space in the left , these are my code :

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/base_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dip"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/base_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity:

```
private void initToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.base_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if( actionBar != null)
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    contentLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_content);
}
```

Is here anything wrong with my code or it should be like this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space on the left is caused by Toolbar's contentInsetStart which by default is 16dp. You can set it to 0 to remove it. Dont forget to add the schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/base_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dip"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/base_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer I want. It's great of you solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1E90FF"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I had tried this , but it didn't work. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: actually what you want? margin left or not?