# Android toolbar not sizing correctly

Tags: android, toolbar

I have an android toolbar and inside the toolbar I have an `editText`, and the `editText` is doing a margin which I don't want.

**Here is a picture:**

[image]

**Here is the toolbar code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/buscador"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:textColorHint="#cccc"
        android:hint="Buscar"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Background of the toolbar:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#333"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is that why there is a blank space on the left in `Toolbar`. It's Toolbar's `contentInsetStart` which by default is 16dp, you can set 0 to remove it:

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Hope this can help:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/buscador"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#666"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:textColorHint="#cccc"
        android:hint="Buscar"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086148/when-add-a-custom-view-in-android-toolbar-there-will-be-a-marginleft) for more information about the `marginLeft` in `Toolbar`.

Comment: my problem is with the width

Comment: I add the `app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"` and `app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` in the answer, please check.

Comment: In order to make your answer more useful for future visitors, please explain what the problem is and how and why your suggestions fix the problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I had added more details about the answer, please check :)